# How to convert date from character to datetime in R to insert into Oracle

Tags: sql, r, oracle, insert

I've got a problem with dates when I insert dates from R into Oracle using `ROracle` package.

I have a simple dataframe

```
dt = c('2022-01-01', '2005-04-01', '2011-10-02')
var = c('sgdsg', 'hjhgjg', 'rurtur')
num = c(165, 1658.5, 8978.12354)

data = data.frame(dt, var, num)%>% 
  mutate(dt = as.Date(dt))
```

I need to insert this dataframe inro Oracle database using the following code

```
data %>% 
  dbWriteTable(
    oracle_con,
    value = .,
    'D_TEST',
    append = T,
    row.names=F,
    overwrite = F
  )
```

where `D_TEST` is a test table in my database.

Hovewer I've got the following results

```
DT                  VAR     NUM
2022-01-01 03:00:00 sgdsg   165
2005-04-01 03:00:00 hjhgjg  1 658.5
2011-10-02 03:00:00 rurtur  8 978.12354
```

As you can see there is an additional time component. I need to get the `00:00:00` insted.
How can I fix the problem?

P.S.
I tried to change the timezone

```
Sys.setenv(TZ = "Europe/Moscow")
Sys.setenv(ORA_SDTZ = "Europe/Moscow")
```

But I didn't help.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include the `CREATE TABLE` statement for your table as it may make a difference if the `DT` column is a `DATE` or a `TIMESTAMP(0)` data type.

Comment: A DATE in Oracle ALWAYS contains a time component, always. If you don't supply one, it defaults to 12:00:00. When your client/tools/code go to get the data back, simply format the DATE columns to the desired shape such as RRRR-DD-MM.  If you need to include a timeszone component to your data, you need to store the values as TIMESTAMP with TIMEZONE (or with local timezone).

Comment: @MT0, @thatjeffsmith Thank you. I changed the column format ot `TIMESTAMP(0)` and it works fine.

Comment: Please post the column data type and the corresponding `NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT`/`NLS_TIMESTAMP_TZ_FORMAT`setting.

Answer (score 0):

Basically what the function [`dbWriteTable`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RJDBC/RJDBC.pdf) is doing is to convert your `Date` variable back to a character

```
> as.character(data$dt)
[1] "2022-01-01" "2005-04-01" "2011-10-02"
```

and taking this string in the `insert` statement (simplified) as follows

```
insert into  tab(col) values ( '2022-01-01');
```

So you can see this will work *allways fine* if your column is `VARCHAR2` (and you convert to `DATE` explicitely later).

If your column is of datatype `DATE` or some `TIMESTAMP` you performs an *implicite conversion* which is *allways potentialy bad* as you may fail when the session mask is other than the data string or you observe some *default timezone shift* (as you did).

So my recomendation is keep the column `VARCHAR2`and cast to `DATE` explicitely.

Comment: I cannot imagine a time (given the sample data) when it is better to store as a `varchar2` vice something that has a date-like characteristics. Indexing, searching by range, and date-like arithmetic all suffer from the need to `cast(..)` in *every single query*. I don't work with Oracle, but I work regularly with SQL Server, PostgreSQL, and SQLite, and in none of those does this method make sense to me. Is there something with Oracle where it is cheaper to `cast` every time?

Comment: Sorry @r2evans you did not catch my point. I **did not** recommend to store *date* or *timestamp* as `VARCHAR2` in Oracle. I *propose* to let the `r` function `dbWriteTable` to store the `r` *Date* attribute as a `VARCHAR2` to *and this is important*  **avoid** an *implicite conversion*  and to *explicitely cast* it to the *propper data type* in th enext step. I'm sorry that this is confusing.

Comment: Hmmm. Okay, I guess I misunderstand *"so my recommendation is"*. Thanks.

Comment: Well yes, @r2evans the *intention* was on *cast to `DATE` explicitely*. But thanks for your comment, one need to be *carefull* in the formulation.